# Столкнулся с ошибками в php, wordpress, woodmart

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Ошибки в media.php не могу найти ответ на них :

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\media.php on line 795

```html
if ( (int) $data['width'] === (int) $size[0] && (int) $data['height'] === (int) $size[1]
```

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\media.php on line 801

```html
if ( $data['width'] >= $size[0] && $data['height'] >= $size[1] )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для того, чтобы найти ответ на них, нужно всего лишь навсего кинуть текст в переводчик (если сам не знаешь ангийский) и потом немного подумать..... тут чётко написано, что ты пытаешься с булевым типом работать как с массивом, то есть по индексу что-то взять...

Comment: Хороший ответ, но он мало чего решает в моем случае)

Comment: Приходи когда научишься [задавать вопросы по ВП](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress). Да-да это вопрос по ВП, а не php.

Comment: @АлександрСтепанов а что он должен был решить? тебе сказали в чём проблема, ну подумай хоть немного почему так происходит....логически заключи .... "у тебя ошибка.....потому что непривычное поведение.....потому что там не массив а булев тип......ну а дальше......" ....надо быть не кодером, а разработчиком. А разработчик логически размышляет и умозаключает, а не просто лапками по клаве бьёт букавки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @SeVlad ну он может и про пыху. потому что  ТС может там что-то ковырял, что и привело к ошибке.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нет. Этот недовопрос чисто по ВП. Но без нужных данных не решается. (да собственно и решать тут нечего. Достаточно провести элементарные действия по вычислению виновного)